# Is there a way to iterate over all child components in React?

Tags: reactjs, filter, find, children

Is there a way to iterate over all child components in React?
I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<Form>
 <FormLine>
  <FormItem>
   <FormInput/>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
   <FormInput/>
  </FormItem>
 </FormLine>
 <FormLine>
  <FormItem>
   <FormInput/>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
   <FormInput/>
  </FormItem>
 </FormLine>
<input type="submit"/>
</Form>
```

Form component looks something like this:

```
export const Form = ({ info, error, success, children, submit, onSubmit }) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [ disabled, setDisabled ] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!submit) return;
        const inputs = getChildrenByTypeDeep(children, ['FormInput']);
        if(inputs) {
            inputs.forEach(i => {
                console.dir(i);
                // I would like to check the values of the form fields somewhere here
            });
        }    
    }, [ children ]);

    return(
        <div className='Form'>
            {success && <div className='Form-success'>{t(success)}</div>}
            {error && <div className='Form-error'>{t(error)}</div>}
            {info && <div className='Form-info'>{t(info)}</div>}
            {children}
            {submit &&
            <input
                type='submit'
                value={t(submit)}
                disabled={disabled}
                onClick={onSubmit ? onSubmit : null}
            />}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I need to check that all FormInput components have a value before enabling the FormSubmit component. To do this, I want to be able to check for value changes in all child input elements inside the Form component.
I've tried using the react-children-utilities and react-nanny packages, but neither finds my FormInput components inside Forms.

react-children-utilites work in development but not in production

```
useEffect(() => {
        //if(!submit) return;
        console.log('Form changed');
        setDisabled(false);
        deepForEach(children, child => {
            if (child && child.type.name === 'FormInput' && child.props.required) {
                const value = child.props.value.trim();
                if(!value) setDisabled(true);
            }
        });    
    }, [ children ]);
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, after googling for a while, I found an article
https://mparavano.medium.com/find-filter-react-children-by-type-d9799fb78292
which explains everything!

First of all, I need to add special prop for my FormInput component:

```
FormInput.propTypes = {
    __TYPE: PropTypes.string,
};

FormInput.defaultProps = {
    __TYPE: 'FormInput',
};
```

After that I can filter children by this prop after building:

```
useEffect(() => {
        //if(!submit) return;
        console.log('Form changed');
        setDisabled(false);
        deepForEach(children, child => {
            if (child && child.props.__TYPE === 'FormInput' && child.props.required) {
                const value = child.props.value.trim();
                if(!value) setDisabled(true);
            }
        });
    }, [ children ]);
```

This is possible because literal string values are not minified.
Many thanks to Michael Paravano for the clarification!

It's a pity that React doesn't provide a tool for recursively bypassing children. It would help not to use third party packages :)